# Python Stored procedure sql injection

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

**Question:**
I would like to know if the below stored procedure is safe from sql injection and I know that the general guideline is to use parametrized query. However, I am not sure how to put parametrized query in a stored procedure.

**Context**:
I am using flask/python to get the data based on the parameters. The data is retrieved from a stored procedure and for the database connection, the code is using pymysql libray.

```
param1 = request.get('param1')
param2 = request.get('param2')
param3 = request.get('param3')

pymysql.callproc('EXEC STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME', (param1, param2, param3))
```

In the stored procedure definition, the parameters are defined and a select query is written. Based on the other parameters, other parameters will be added in the select query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `PROCEDURE_NAME`(PARAM1 VARCHAR(500),PARAM2 VARCHAR(500),PARAM3 VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN

set @query=concat("select * from TABLE1 WHERE column1 = SOME_VALUE");

IF param1 is not null THEN
set @query=concat(@query," AND COLUMN2 like '%"PARAM1"%'");
END iF;

IF param2 is not null THEN
set @query=concat(@query," AND COLUMN3 like '%"PARAM2"%'");
END iF;

IF param3 is not null THEN
set @query=concat(@query," AND COLUMN4 like '%"PARAM3"%'");
END iF;

SELECT @query1;
prepare st from @query1;
execute st;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course not injection safe:

While a prepared statement doesn't support execution of multiple statements, you can grab other data by injecting `UNION`:

```
call procedure_name("%' UNION SELECT user, bank_account from bankaccounts WHERE '1' != '", NULL, NULL);
```

Also don't forget to close your statement with `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`.

This would be injection safe (assuming columns in TABLE1 are defined as NOT NULL):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `PROCEDURE_NAME`(PARAM1 VARCHAR(500),PARAM2 VARCHAR(500),PARAM3 VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN

SET @p1:=@p2:=@p3:= '%';
PREPARE stmt FROM "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE column1 = 'SOME_VALUE' AND
COLUMN2 LIKE ? AND COLUMN3 LIKE ? AND COLUMN4 LIKE ?";

IF param1 is not null THEN
   SET @p1:= param1;
END iF;
IF param2 is not null THEN
   SET @p2:= param2;
END iF;
IF param3 is not null THEN
   SET @p3:= param3;
END iF;

EXECUTE stmt USING @p1,@p2,@p3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: Thank you! I suggested this answer to my team and will use this.